# Writing webresponse to HEAP results in garbage when printing

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I am working on an Arduino with a WiFi shield. Currently, I am making a web request on the shield. I am trying to use `malloc()` to write the response to heap. Right now, when printing out `_buffer`, I get the response with all the headers followed by a bunch of garbage as pictured below:
[image: Serial output with headers followed by garbage]

```
char *NetConn::capture()
{
    if (_client.available())
    {
        if (_buffer) // RELEASE ANY DATA HELD IN THE BUFFER IF THE BUFFER EXISTS
        {
            free(_buffer);
        }                                                             // KEEP TRACK OF HOW LARGE THE BUFFER CURRENTLY IS TO PREPARE FOR ANY OVERFLOW
        _buffer = (char *)malloc(_client.available() * sizeof(char)); // INITIALIZE THE BUFFER

        Serial.println(_client.available()); // _client.available() returns 550 (size of payload)

        char c;
        int index = 0;
        while (_client.available())
        {
            c = _client.read();
            _buffer[index] = c;

            index++;
        }
        int size = sizeof(_buffer) / sizeof(char);
        Serial.println(size); // This is writing 2 for some reason
    }

    return _buffer;
}
```

I should mention that `_client` is an instance of an Arduino WiFi client.

I'm very very new to low level memory management and am trying to get a grasp of the whole memory management thing. I'm used to working with the comforts of high-level languages; However I am trying to branch out. Please help me understand what is going on here with an explanation as I am very new. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean "this is writing 2"?

Comment: @John when I run `Serial.println(size);`, the number 2 is returned - this isn't the value I'd expect; Shouldn't it be 550, the size of the payload? **EDIT:** oops - I just realized I had `Serial.println(_buffer);` not `Serial.println(size);` as it should've been in the snippet. Hopefully that clarifies!

Comment: `_buffer` is likely a `char *` right? Pointers on arduino are only 2 bytes, so size should only return 2. `index` holds the number of read bytes. Use that.

Comment: You're somehow printing out whatever `capture()` returns, right? I'm not sure what your buffer should hold, but it looks like it's not null-terminated. Allocate `_client.available() * sizeof(char) + 1` bytes. Assign this value to a variable as well!!! Don't count on `_client.available()` remaining constant. Read that many bytes from `_client.read()`, then set the last byte to 0.

Comment: Bingo! Thank you John!

Comment: Also consider the possibility that you call `capture` when the packet has only been partially received. I don't know how arduino wifi shields work, so not sure if this is an issue or not.